# как получить объект класса родителя из класса наследника?

Tags: c++, ооп

как получить объект класса родителя из класса наследника?

к примеру

```
class A : public B
{

}
```

как мне получить B имея объект типа a ?

Comment: Что значит "получить B"? Вы и так его имеете :), поскольку A **является** B... А если вы хотите именно `B b;` — то вот так и получить.

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, грубо говоря, хочется из объекта A сконструировать чистый объект B. Аналогично если бы B было полем  A, и мы просто его забрали бы

Comment: A a;    B* pb = &a;  объектом будет (*pb) или  B b = static_cast<B>(a);

Comment: в базовом классе конструктором копирования `B(B const&)` очень просто получить. вы пробовали сами? копия : `A a; B b(a);` ; ссылка : `B & b(a);`

Answer (score 0):

Как Вам уже подсказали в комментариях объект класса A является собой совокупностью объекта класса B и полей класса А.

Т.е. буквально в памяти объект класса А хранится таким образом

```
|поля класса A| поля класса B |
```

Таким образом компилятору не составит труда привести объект класса А к объекту класса B:

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
    public:
    int b;

    B(int b) : b(b){}
};



class A: public B {
    public:
    int a;

    A (int a, int b) : B(b), a(a) {}
};


int main(int, char**) {

    A derived (1, 2);
    
    std::cout << "Constructed: "<< derived.a << ", " << derived.b << "\n";
    // Вывод в консоли:
    // Constructed: 1, 2

    B basic_from_derived = static_cast<B>(derived); // Это преобразование происходит прямо во время компиляции
    std::cout << "Basic: "<< basic_from_derived.b <<"\n"; // Естественно, поле а нам уже не доступно
    // Вывод в консоли: 
    // Basic: 2 
}
```

В случае множественного наследования этот код будет работать немного не так, как ожидается, но это уже отельный вопрос.

Comment: static_cast как бы не обязателен, но на мой вкус лучше его оставить, чтобы было видно, что этот кусок кода не ошибка, что Автор именно хотел обрезать объект A до состояния B. Говорят, что этот приём называется slicing (обрезка), но лично я не встречал в практике этого термина.

Comment: слишком много кода лишь  для показа того, что  объекту базового класса можно присвоить объект производного. Именно static_cast<B>(derived) выдает то, о чем говорится в вопросе, а basic_from_derived это уже другой объект.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я ничего не понял, возможно вы правы.